# Center the layout after hiding the Android button programmatically

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button

I have one **LinearLayout** and it is **center_horizontal**.

It contains three buttons: *left*, *middle* and *right*.  All were fixed in same row.

When I hide the *right* button programmatically it will hide the button, but not center the *left* and *middle* buttons.

I want the *left* and *middle* buttons to be centered in the layout when I am hiding the *right* button.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a view invisible, makes it only invisible which has its effect.

Try using `gone` instead of `invisible` and you are done!

Comment: @SathishKumarJ no, that wont help, he needs gone visibility to stop the button from occupying the space

Comment: I think the OP means the opposite

Comment: yeah @SathishKumarJ thats what i need

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
yourbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

What it does is, it stops the button from occupying any space on your screen which will in turn allow the other buttons to shift.

Just keeping it invisible will just hide the button from view, but it will still occupy the space and not allow the other buttons to adjust

Comment: This answer is a very low quality

Comment: @xenteros actually it is the exact answer he needs. I had explained all this in the comments above. anyway, updated it and added the info

Comment: I commented when your answer was one one liner with different code

Comment: the code was the same @xenteros, i edited the info :)

Comment: anyway i hope it helps the guy, thats what matters :) ty for pointing out that it needed info ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following settings:
1) Set visibitlity to `gone`
2) Set the `width` of ALL elements to `0dp` and the `weight` of ALL to `1`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your three buttons are placed in `LinearLayout` with the orientation of `horizontal`, now use this code in `Java` file:

```
rightbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```